# Updating gcc in openshift

Tags: gcc, openshift

Is there a way to upgrade or atleast copy a standalone version of **gcc** in the **openshift** server. I recently created a dev app and my project needs **c++0x** feature support.

The **gcc** that was present in the small gear was **4.4.7**, but I need version **4.7 or above**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading the sources to your gear (into your ~/app-root/data directory) and compiling it yourself, but it's possible that some of it's dependencies won't be met.  Otherwise you can enter a request here: openshift.uservoice.com and get users to vote on it.

Comment: [vote here](https://openshift.uservoice.com/forums/258655-ideas/suggestions/7160125--update-the-compiler-chain-gcc5-0)